# Exporting ReportViewer to Excel - Line width variation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formatting, reportviewer

I am creating reports using the Microsoft ReportViewer control.  I am encountering some formatting issues when exporting the reports into Excel.

The problem is that I am specifying a line width of 1pt in ReportViewer, which is the smallest line possible (or is it?).   When the export is done, the line widths in Excel are all thick borders.

I am trying to figure out how to get the line widths to be standard lines in Excel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was on the right track..  In fact, the smallest line possible is 0.0882mm, and not 1pt.

After setting the line to 0.0882mm, the line width was normal in Excel.